# Using JavaScript template literals to output a value for the background property in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-literals

I know the code at large is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), but I particularly would like to combine [Javascript Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to use a string for the value for a [background CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

```
var bg=$("#hp-row1-1 > div.fp-bg").css('background-image').split('), url(');
if(bg.length==2) {
  bg2 = `<div style="background: url(${bg[1].replace(/\s+/g, '/')}"></div>`;
  console.log(bg2);
  $("#hp-row1-1 > div.fp-bg").attr('style', 'background: ' + bg[0] + ') no-repeat center top !important;');
  $(bg2).insertAfter("#hp-row1-1");
};
<div style="background: url("http://www.davidnguyen.us/sinfulcolors.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/HOME_Nudes_M_414x500.jpg")"></div>
```

How do I remove the quotes which are wrapping the url:

```
url("xxxxxx image xxxxxx")
```

So it is like:

```
url(xxxxxx image xxxxxx)
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**
Tried the following based on what Hemant suggested.

```
var bg=$("#hp-row1-1 > div.fp-bg").css('background-image').split('), url(');
if(bg.length==2) { 
bg2 = `<div style="width:500px; height: 500px; background: url(${bg[1].replace(/\s+/g, '/')}"></div>`;
console.log(bg2);
bg[0] = bg[0].replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1');
console.log(bg[0])
  $("#hp-row1-1 > div.fp-bg").css({
    "background": `url(${bg[0]}) no-repeat center top !important;`});
  $(bg2).insertAfter("#hp-row1-1");
};

    <div style="background: url("http://www.davidnguyen.us/sinfulcolors.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/HOME_Nudes_M_414x500.jpg")"></div>
```

Figured this:

```
bg[0] = bg[0].replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1');
```

Would strip the quotes in the `url("path/to/image")`;

But still getting:

```
<div style="width:500px; height: 500px; background: url("http://www.davidnguyen.us/sinfulcolors.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/HOME_Nudes_M_414x500.jpg")"></div>
```

Comment: first of all, you didn't close your `url()` in the template-- You don't have a closing parenthesis. hope its a typo.

Comment: It would help if you provided a real [mcve] (ideally as a live demo, there's a button for that on the editor). It's unclear where your data is coming from.

Comment: You have the closing brace and closing parenthesis in the wrong order.

Comment: @trincot hey thanks, can you tell me where?

Comment: At the very end of the string ``bg2 = `<div style .....``. Or not really reversed, but missing one `)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `imgPath` is a variable with background url, you can do this

```
const bg = `<div style="background: url(${imgPath})"></div>`;
```

OR in jQuery

```
$("#bg").css({
  "background":`url( ${imgPath} )`
})
```